# JS function in generated html script won't run contents

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function

```
function runcode(code) {
var tag = document.createElement("script");
document.body.appendChild(tag);
tag.innerHTML = code;
}
```

And when I call this

```
certainValue = "test";
anotherValue = "alert('hi');";
runcode("function " + certainValue + "() {" + anotherValue + "}");
```

And then call this in the Chrome J's console

```
test
```

It tells me the function code. But when I call

```
test();
```

nothing happens. Why?

Comment: For me the alert happens, at least when executed from the console.

Comment: @H.B. I will get back to you when I get home. I remembered that the function worked, but the alert didn't. I might have a syntax error

Comment: It happens because you are adding brackets to the end of 'certainValue' in the runcode function, so it ends up being test() in the first case and test();() in the second

Comment: I see. My computer cord just broke, so I will get back to you as soon as I can.